# Using mod_rewrite to make Blog URLs more SEO Friendly

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to turn my blog URLs into a more SEO friendly format using mod_rewrite. All of my articles are stored in a simple MySQL database. Each blog article url looks like this:

`http://www.test.com/blog?id=20&category=online%20php%20tutorials&pagename=how%20to%20customize%20functions`

I have managed to to make them look like this using mod_rewrite:

`http://www.test.com/blog/online-php-tutorials/how-to-customize-functions/20`

Here is my code that I paced in my .htaccess file:

`RewriteRule ^blog/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /blog?id=$3&category=$1&pagename=$2 [L]`

So what happens is this: When I click on the URL `http://www.test.com/blog/online-php-tutorials/how-to-customize-functions/20`, all of my CSS and images are not loading because it is trying to load them from a directory that does not actually exists. How would I load the files without having to create multiple directories that contain my sites CSS files and images?

Comment: Use absolute references for your CSS and JS and it will load them relative to the root of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use root identifier `/` in your path. This will point the DocumentRoot of your server. Let me explain How this works

For an image like this:

```
<img src='test.jpg' />
```

Browser/Server will find it as `http://www.test.com/blog/online-php-tutorials/how-to-customize-functions/20/test.jpg'` but if you use `/` before the path

```
<img src='/test.jpg' />
```

It will look for it in `http://www.test.com/test.jpg`

#### Another Technique

Use full path in your files like:

```
<img src='http://test.com/test.jpg' />
```

Comment: @three3, Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You will want your CSS paths to be based on the root of your domain. If your CSS file is at `http://example.com/includes/style.css`, you should use `/includes/style.css` to include that file instead of `includes/style.css`.